# Color words based on gramatical categories?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, writing

Does there exist any package to color words based on grammatical class? (Noun, verb, adjective... etc).

Something like `rainbow-mode` for grammar instead of colors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could cobble one together; there has been software that analyses the structure of sentences for decades. I wouldn't set your expectations too high though. Consider the following sentences:

```
Time flies like an arrow.
Fruit flies like a banana.
```

Unless the software understands context the way a human would, it will be guessing most of the time.

Comment: It should be possible to get *reasonable* results with NLTK, although I didn't test this example - see: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet

Comment: In practice that particular example is well-known, so probably any software which is reasonably up to date will at least have a special case for it.